# MVC 5 request validation is not enforced in localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xss

I am working in ASP.NET MVC 5, somehow I have an issue that I do not understand. If I issue a post request with a form variable having "" value in my localhost, it does NOT throw any request validation exception. If I published the application and make a same post request with the violating form variable from another machine, it will throw the request validation exception. Does anyone know the reason for this different behaviour? Please note that I had removed the Glimpse in the web.config. Thank you so much.

Comment: It is better to put your controller and view model here to check.

Comment: Check the difference between IIS versions.